# C# Windows forms application page-up page-down

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

[a busy cat http://non-98.ucoz.com/browser_choice_large.png](http://non-98.ucoz.com/browser_choice_large.png)
!

I want to add "this thing"  (I don't know its name in english
:D)  in my widows forms application.

Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean the scrollbar?

Comment: So you want your form to have a non-fixed size but the content to have fixed and set the view of your form via the scrollbar?

Comment: It is called "scrollbar".  You get one by setting the AutoScrollMinSize property to a sufficiently large value.  Or by letting Winforms sort it out automatically by setting AutoScroll to True.

Comment: But when i am moving scrollbar things in form are not moving. Did you understood???

Comment: I want scrollbar to such effect on form as in browser

Comment: You have to set the `AutoScroll` property to `true` for the `Control` you want to be scrollable. If you're having a `panel` within your form that you want to be scrollable, set its `AutoScroll` property to true, along with the fixed size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the comments already noted you need to use the [Form.AutoScroll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a62htd5x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property and set the form size to be fixed. Then a scrollbar will appear on your form if there's a control within it that surpasses the field of view of your form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ScrollableControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It has some properties to control the scrollbar.